# consequence for illegal double word plays

Tags: scrabble

When a player uses tiles that do not properly spell an acceptable word and their opponent successfully challenges, the offending player loses their turn.  What is the consequence when a player makes two or more words without remaining in the required row/column that they started?

Comment: That is not a legal play, so wouldn't they have to make a legal play instead?

Answer (score 4):

Not an official rule, but common sense.

In the ideal world, we all follow the rules. But sometimes people "forget" a rule or they try to cheat. The best way is to call them out and let them correct their mistake. And if they persist in this behaviour, find somebody else to play with.

Comment: If I could upvote this more than once I would.   Everyone make mistakes when playing games, occasionally deliberately (although I've only seen that in two people my whole life).  There generally isn't a ' consequence' of this as the asker states.  Just a matter of common sense and trying to resolve it fairly.  I'm glad my gaming group are nice people who point out missed rules in each other favour as we want the game to be fair.